# Type mismatch in recursive generic class

Tags: kotlin, generics, recursion, type-mismatch

I have this code, definition of my class:

```
abstract class AbstractKeyNode<K: Comparable<K>, NT: AbstractKeyNode<K, NT>>(val key: K) {
    var parent: NT? = null
        internal set
    var left: NT? = null
        internal set
    var right: NT? = null
        internal set
    fun hasChild(): Boolean = hasLeft() || hasRight()
    fun hasParent(): Boolean = parent != null
    fun hasLeft(): Boolean = left != null
    fun hasRight(): Boolean = right != null
}
```

Why I get type mismatch error, if I try to create variable NT and assign into it this?
Something like that:

> val node: NT = this

Why it doesn't work ? NT is actually AbstractKeyNode too, or not ?

Comment: you get a type mismatch error is because the NT type parameter is not yet known at the point where you are trying to assign this to it.

Comment: Okay, how can I assign into left, right, parent "this" ?

Comment: Should I use AbstractKeyNode<K, NT> for left, right and parent ?

Comment: That’s the best you can do. There’s no way to guarantee that the subclasses always use themselves as the type of `NT` so assuming `this` is a valid `NT` is not allowed.

Comment: There is no alternative but to do the unsafe cast.  Your types are already as good as they can be.  You will have to write `this as NT` and ignore the warning.